# How to serve the data returned from laravel Storage::disk('private')->get($file) as PDF

Tags: laravel, pdf, blob, laravel-filesystem

My question is about the problem in link below :

[Understanding file storage and protecting contents Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57462558/understanding-file-storage-and-protecting-contents-laravel-5)

I need to use the same method mentioned in above example but instead of an image I need to provide a download link for PDF file or a link to open PDF file in browser and I can't do that because, as mentioned in above example's comments The `Storage::disk('private')->get($file)` returns the CONTENT of the file NOT the URL.

Please tell me how can I convert the row data (content of file) to a file and provide the link for the users inside the view.

Comment: The user `aceraven777`  answered the example link I hope he answers this too :)

Comment: When you click on link pdf open in browser new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#downloading-files) you can simply use the `download` method on the `Storage` facade.

From your controller, return the result of the command.

`return Storage::disk('private')->download($file);`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It worked exactly as I expected.

Comment: one more question, how can I open the file in browser instead of downloading it ?

Comment: @kianooshAzarvandi You need to get URL and then add this URL in an anchor tag with the target `blank`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @kianooshAzarvandi I'm not entirely sure if Laravel 5.1 supports File Responses but you can try to `return response()->file($pathToFile)`. If this doesn't work try `return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf', 'Content-Disposition' => "inline; filename=\"{$name}\""]);` What you are doing here is modifying the Content-Disposition header, so that the browser will display the file rather than try to download it.

Comment: Undefined variable: pathToFile

Comment: The file is being served through `Storage::disk('private')` and the path is inside private folder which is not accessible without serving it using `Storage::disk('private')`

Answer (score 3):

You should follow the below steps:

I have store pdf file into `storage/app/pdf`

In controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index(Request $request, $file)
{   

    $file = storage_path('app/pdf/') . $file . '.pdf';

    if (file_exists($file)) {

        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'
        ];

        return response()->file($file, $headers);
    } else {
        abort(404, 'File not found!');
    }        
}
```

if laravel below 5.2:
Add `use Response;` above controller class in the controller.

```
public function index(Request $request, $file)
{   

    $file = storage_path('app/pdf/') . $file . '.pdf';

    return Response::make(file_get_contents($file), 200, [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$file.'"'

    ]);       
}
```

In `web.php`

```
Route::get('/preview-pdf/{file}', 'Yourcontroller@index');
```

In the blade view:

```
<a href="{{ URL('/preview-pdf/'.$file )}}" target="_blank">PDf</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried it but it returns a blank page with the url of file in top-left corner

Comment: @kianooshAzarvandi Can you check the URL of the file is correct or not when black page showing?

Comment: For the record I use this : `$url = Storage::disk('private')->url($file);` in a separate controller which is responsible for creating route to the link of files

Comment: @kianooshAzarvandi I have tested in my laravel project for you and it is working. Let me know any issue.

Comment: You are not making it private, the whole thing is about file security and meanwhile 
serving the file through Storage::disk('private') only to authenticated users and it is done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57462558/understanding-file-storage-and-protecting-contents-laravel-5

Comment: @kianooshAzarvandi No no, It is a private folder which is not accessible directly like `http://yourdomain.com/filename`.

Comment: @kianooshAzarvandi Also private means `644` file permission right?

Comment: @kianooshAzarvandi If you want to serve only authenticated user should use `auth()`. I have updated my controller code.

Comment: result is the same,opens a new tab and then downloads the file, I need it to open the file

Comment: @kianooshAzarvandi Replace return download to `file`. I have updated

Comment: Error : Call to undefined method: 
League\Flysystem\Filesystem::file

Comment: @kianooshAzarvandi Your Laravel version is below 5.2? right then use another method. I have added in my controller.